# is there a way to ONLY compile POSIX API

Tags: linux, gcc, makefile, posix, gnu

I am developing a system that must be fully POSIX compatible

I am developing this on Fedora Core 14 with gcc and c++

I do not want to use anything that is not POSIX

How do I ensure I maintain this?

is there a compiler setting?

I am using Codeblocks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, there's no "magic compiler switch" to insure you use only Posix APIs.

You can get the POSIX spec here:

- http://www.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/toc.htm
- http://www.opengroup.org/bookstore/catalog/c082.htm

This suite allows you to check your application for conformance to the POSIX API:

- http://www.knosof.co.uk/poschk.html

Comment: great, thanks for the info - probably appropriate under a different SO question, but do you have any resources about using POSIX api with c++?

Answer (score 1):

This does not really have anything to do with the compiler. POSIX specifies utilities, interfaces and the accompanying header files - the compiler is only concerned with the specifics of the programming language.

That said, if the header file set that you are using is well-implemented you should be able to enable/disable the feature sets that you are using with proper `-D` and `-U` options for `gcc`.

For example including `fcntl.h` will not allow access to `fallocate()` unless `_GNU_SOURCE` has been defined. With the same header, you need to define `_POSIX_C_SOURCE` to `200809L` or greater for the `F_DUPFD_CLOEXEC` [`fcntl()`](http://linux.die.net/man/2/fcntl) to be available.